# WebStorm не отображает ошибки ESlint

Tags: typescript, webstorm, eslint

Установил ESLint v7.32.0 под свой WebStorm 2020.1, в эдиторе вроде ошибки показываются подчеркиаются, исправляются и вроде бы все работает, но когда я открываю окно ошибок что бы посмотреть все ошибки либо все ошибки в текущем файле то у меня там либо пусто либо отображаются ошибки только `typescript` типа `Error:(72, 63) TS2304: Cannot find name 'some_undefined_var'.`
А вот если например ошибка именно по правилу ESLint то в этом окне пусто.

Вопрос: Как мне отобразить все ошибки полностью включая тайпскипт и все ошибки ESLint в одном окне?

Вот пример окна, когда в файле ошибок 10+ по правилам ESLint и одна просто в несуществующей переменной:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD**

В настройках кейпамоыв это окно присутствует, но в самом меню его нету, может быть есть какая-то опция включающая его?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, Вы используете старую версию WebStorm, где еще нет [Problems](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2020/06/webstorm-2020-2-eap-5/#new_tool_window_for_going_over_problems_in_your_code) tool window, показывающего одновременно и ошибки компилятора, и ошибки линтеров/инспекшенов. У вас открыто окно **Typescript**, там показываются только ошибки компилятора. Попробуйте запустить **Code > Inspect Code**, тогда в окне **Inspections results** будут в том числе и ошибки ESLint

Comment: Да вроде в списке оно есть, я пмню у меня была такая проблема в InteliJ, там нужно было поставить галку для компилятора, "Make project automatically", или как то так, типа ребилдить проект при каждом сохранении, и только тогда появилось это окно в меню, а в WebStorm я такой опции не вижу

Comment: какую версию WebStorm вы используете? Упомянутая вами опция IDEA относится только к компиляции java и не имеет никакого отношения к инспекшенам или линтерам

Comment: WebStorm 2020.1

Comment: Problems tool window появилсь только в 2020.2. В 2020.1 вам нужно использовать **Code > Inspect Code**, как я и написала в ответе выше